# Radio Button value retrieval using servlets

Tags: java, servlets, radio-button

I'm quite new to the process of web development, so I apoligise if this seems a really silly question.

Basically, I'm creating a servlet whereby a user will answer 'yes' or 'no' to three 3 questions, and then submit the form.

What I wish to do is to retrieve the value of each button, and store it a data structure such as an array, where I can perform a check on it. However, I am a little lost at this point. Is there a method in java I can call on each button, something along the lines of getValue()?

A look at the code ive developed so far:

```
out.println("<FORM ACTION=\"Game\" METHOD = \"POST\">" +
        "<b>Question 1: Are you over the age of 25?. </b><br> <br>" +

        "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"rad1Q1\" onclick = \"getAnswer('a')\"> Yes " +
        "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"rad2Q1\" onclick = \"getAnswer('b')\"> No<br>" +

        "<br><br><b>Question 2: Are you from planet earth. </b><br> <br>" +

        "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"rad1Q2\" onclick = \"getAnswer('a')\"> Yes " +
        "<input type = \"radio\" name = \"rad2Q2\" onclick = \"getAnswer('b')\"> No <br>"
```

Comment: The values selected will be included in the parameters of the POST request.  BTW - that HTML, combined with your question, makes me think you should learn more about how HTML works before attempting servlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input values in the html form will be submitted as request parameters to the servlet. 
In the servlet where the form is submitting to, you can do

```
String rad1Q1 = request.getParameter("rad1Q1");
```

to get the selected value.

I do suggest you do put the html code in the jsp tho instead of servlet to make the code more clear and easier to maintain.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help :) For the purpose of this problem I will be using servlets, although I will keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 0):

These buttons are totally client side, but JSP is a server side scripting language, so you must submit your form & check the value of buttons at server side or simply use javascript to check which one is selected(you can also use AJAX, but it seems to be a little confusing for you).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, can you please post more info?, like what are you using?, spring or struts, and how your "GAME" servlet looks like.

In general the process can be:

Write a regular html or jsp file that have the form and the questions that you like, the radio should have a unique name (I can see that you are already doing that) and in the form you will need to add also a submit button that will trigger the action of the form, so the action of the form must to be the url of one of your servlets.

In the target servlet you will get the radio buttons by the name that you give then in the html or jsp, for for example for rad1Q1 you will do something like request.getParameter("rad1Q1") and you will get the value of that field.

That is one way to do it there are many ways but with your experience this look like the simpler approach.